# What is the mechanism by which objects feel the electrostatic force?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law, thought-experiment

This is more of a conceptual question than a mathematical one, but you may answer however you wish.

Suppose we imagine a universe with a single proton in it, then magically create an electron one light year away from it. It is my understanding that the proton will eventually feel the electrostatic force exerted on it by the electron one year later, but how? What causes it to suddenly know of the electron's existence a whole light year away?

The answer I have gotten has been that when the electron is created, it immediately sends a ripple through the underlying electric field that alters the field while propagating radially outwards from the electron at the speed of light. When the "alteration ripple" reaches the proton, it is now able to feel the electrostatic force from the electron.

My main issue with this is that I've always thought (perhaps incorrectly?) of the electric field as a representation of the electrostatic force at all points in space, so saying that the electron's electric field contribution propagates radially at the speed of light just sounds to me like the electric force exerted by the electron is carried radially outwards at the speed of light - which to me, doesn't really answer the question as to *what* is "carrying" the electrostatic force from the electron to the proton and to all other points in space.

So now I ask: What is the mechanism by which objects feel the electrostatic force?

Comment: This may help - [What is the cause of electric force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/600597/37364)

Comment: The electrostatic field IS the effect of one charge on the other. That's the definition of the field. When we say that a field of 1V/m creates a force of 1N on a charge of 1 Coulomb, then the force of 1N is the actual physics (or, better, the acceleration that that charge will experience depending on the mass of the test charge). "The field" is merely a human abstraction of that acceleration event. It's NOT the primal physical reality, even though the constant talk about "fields" in the theory suggest that "philosophically the field comes first". It doesn't.

Comment: You are confused between classical electrodynamics, from which the term "electrostatics" derives https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatics and applies to accumulation of charges like the ones carried by the proton and electron. The proton and electron are quantum entities in the mains stream physics and the description has to be quantum mechanical, the potential of attraction between proton and electron entering in the equations . The distance you assign is so large that the wavefunction solution will give zero probability for attraction between the two.

Answer (score 1):

As is usual in Physics, the same phenomenon can be explained at different levels of accuracy with different models. To maintain conceptual clarity, it is crucial to avoid mixing them.

Let me answer the question illustrating the previous statement. The attraction between two far opposite charges can be analyzed using three different physical models.

1. [Action at a distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance). It is the original model introduced by Newton for gravity. The force one body exerts on another depends on the distance, and its presence is assumed to be a property of the system of the two bodies without the need for further explanation. It is the reason for Newton's sentence *[hypotheses non fingo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotheses_non_fingo)* (in Latin). With such a model, it is meaningless to ask for deeper explanations. However, as a consequence, the interaction appears to be *instantaneous*.
2. Action through an intermediate field. The field concept looks redundant in interactions between stationary motions (two particles at rest or moving uniformly on a straight line). However, when particles accelerate, it becomes clear that the field acquires an independent life, obeys its own equations of motion, and becomes a new physical system with its properties. With the field model, it is meaningful to consider the force between two charges as mediated by the electromagnetic field (that becomes the *mechanism* underlying the interaction). Notice that the field model is not equivalent to the action at a distance model but reduces to that in the static case.
3. At an even more accurate level of modeling, we substitute the classical field concept with a quantum field. A more complex model, compatible with the microscopic laws of quantum mechanics, transforms the interaction between a proton and an electron into an interacting system described in terms of the quantum fields of electron, proton, and photons. At the simplest level, this model substitutes the classical field with photons as *a mechanism* for interaction. Of course, the additional accuracy of the Quantum Electrodynamics model is reflected in the possibility of explaining phenomena beyond the possibilities of the classical theory (for example, emission phenomena by atoms).

Answer (score 0):

We can made the situation more realistic by supposing a kind of generator that accumulate charges. What happens really is a process of separation of charges, where a previously neutral environment is now separated in a object with positive charges (for example) and a neighbourhood of negative charges. The object can be moved far from its surroundings.

A point P far away has initially zero electric field. The process of the interaction between charges, as they are being separated, generates electromagnetic waves. That waves propagates at the speed of light and 'update' the fields at P. When all the movement stops and the charges are in a static position, the final situation is a static electric field.