# Induction in a magnetostatic scenario

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetostatics

A charge is moving at constant velocity along the **x-axis**.

Question: is there induction occurring, OR, only magnetostatic fields updating as the charge moves at a constant velocity?

Let's say the charge was at **x = -0.1** (time **t = 1**), and now it's at **x = 0** (time **t = 1.1**).

(Please assume that it has been moving with a **constant velocity** for many days.)

Let's look at the field at a fixed point of **(0, 1, 0)**.

Some argue that this should hold for magnetostatic fields too: **∇ X E = -dB/dt**

**-dB/dt** is easily found at **(0, 1, 0)** - check.

But **∇ X E = 0** at **(0, 1, 0)** both before (**t = 1**) and after (**t = 1.1**).

Thus you have a change of **dB/dt** but a zero **∇ X E**.

If you say that **∇ X E != 0**, you're positing ***additional*** fields *beyond* the **radial E** fields of the constant velocity charge. What are these extra fields?

But we'd like to say that all that exists in terms of **E** fields for a constant velocity moving charge are its **radial E** fields, such that **∇ X E = 0** is really true.

Thus either a constant velocity moving charge has **non-radial E** fields (given that -**dB/dt** at **(0, 1, 0)** is ever **non-zero**), OR, magnetostatic **B** fields, being not radiation fields, don't have **∇ X E = -dB/dt** apply to them, and therefore only radial **E** fields exist.

(The question is based on a similar question posted by another user, but there was a bit of confusion, so I believe this question distills the meaning of that other question. Or if not it's a worthy question in its own right.)

**Follow up question:**

Thanks; sounds like all the answer is that as Coloumb's law field needs to update with the movement of the particle, the transition mixes old and new fields. All are radial, but not spherically symmetrical, providing a non-zero curl, yet no radiation? They come about in the ordinary course of the retarded update of the field per Coulomb's law...?

Comment: Please use MathJaX to write equations on this site.  You can find a tutorial on how to do so [on our sister Mathematics site.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But $\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf E = 0$ at $(0, 1, 0)$ both before $t = 1$ and after $t = 1.1$.

This isn't true precisely because $\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf E = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t} \ne 0.$

> If you say that $\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf E \ne 0$, you're positing additional fields beyond the radial E fields of the constant velocity charge. What are these extra fields?

This isn't something we are positing, it is required by the Maxwell-Faraday equation. Yes, the field isn't radial. [It can be written as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Transformation_of_the_electromagnetic_field) $\mathbf E = (E'_x,\gamma E'_y, \gamma E'_z)$, where $\mathbf E'$ is the field in the reference frame in which the charge is at rest and is given by Coulomb's law, $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$, $v$ is the speed of the charge and $c$ is the speed of light. $\mathbf E$ is not curl-free. Yes, the non-zero curl (i.e. the deviation from Coulomb's law) can be interpreted as being due to (or required by) the time-varying magnetic field, i.e. "induction".

> But we'd like to say that all that exists in terms of E fields for a
> constant velocity moving charge are its radial E fields, such that $\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf E = 0 $.

This is only approximately true, to the extent the velocity of the charge is small (compared to the speed of light). This is sometimes called the quasistatic approximation.

Comment: Electric field vectors point to the charge, so the field is radial. It just isn't spherically symmetric, field on the equator is stronger than one on the poles.

Comment: @JánLalinský I understand radial to mean strictly along the position vector relative to the charge. This isn't the case for $\gamma > 1$, which leads to a field component perpendicular to the position vector.

Comment: But the electric field vector of a moving charge *is* pointing in the same (or opposite) direction as the radius vector centered at the moving charge. Component perpendicular to radius vector is zero.

Comment: @JánLalinský: Maybe the confusion is over the "present position" vs. the "retarded position" of the moving charge?  I do agree with you and so does [Feynman.](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_26.html)

Comment: You are right, my mistake was in not accounting for length contraction, and thank you @MichaelSeifert for the link to Feynman.

Comment: Thanks; sounds like all the answer is that as Coloumb's law field needs to update with the movement of the particle, the transition mixes old and new fields. All are radial, but not spherically symmetrical, providing a non-zero curl, yet no radiation? They come about in the ordinary course of the retarded update of the field per Coulomb's law...?

Comment: Also, while the experts are here, I have a point that I'm not sure about and have been even foolish enough to debate. Namely, let's say there is a radiation field from an accelerating particle, if it gets "absorbed" in matter, what mechanism accounts for the field decreasing in amplitude post absorption?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, you can arrive at this result either via the Lorentz transformation of the Coulomb field, or the retarded scalar and vector potentials (see the link to the Feynman lectures provided by Michael Seifert). How it's obtained is ultimately immaterial, as long as it satisfies Maxwell's equations. As for your second question, this isn't really related to your original inquiry and so should be as a separate question, but here are some relevant keywords: absorption coefficient, extinction coefficient, complex permittivity/refractive index, electromagnetic wave equation in lossy medium.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...

Answer (score 6):

Maxwell's equations $$\begin{align} \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} &= -\frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}, \qquad \qquad \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}= 4 \pi \rho, \\  \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{B} &= \frac{4\pi}{c} \vec{j} +\frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}, \quad \; \; \,\vec{\nabla}  \cdot \vec{B}=0, \end{align} \tag{1} \label{eq1}$$ (Gauss sytem used) hold *always*, of course also in your scenario (being, by the way, *not* a magnetostatic one). The charge density $\rho$ and the current density $\vec{j}$ of a point charge $q$ moving with constant velocity $\vec{V}= V \vec{e}_x$ along the $x$-axis are given by $$\rho(t,x,y,z) = q \delta(x-Vt) \delta(y) \delta(z),\qquad \vec{j}(t,x,y,z) = \rho(t,x,y,z)\vec{V}. \tag{2} \label{eq2}$$  The corresponding electromagnetic field is most easily obtained by a Lorentz transformation of the field strength tensor of a pure Coulomb field in the reference frame where the charge is at rest to the one where the charge moves with constant velocity $\vec{V}$: $$\begin{align}     E_x(t,x,y,z) &=\frac{q \gamma (x-Vt)}{[\gamma^2 (x-Vt)^2+y^2+z^2]^{3/2}}, \\ E_y(t,x,y,z) &=\frac{q \gamma y}{[\gamma^2 (x-Vt)^2+y^2+z^2]^{3/2}}, \\
E_z(t,x,y,z) &= \frac{q \gamma z}{[\gamma^2 (x-Vt)^2+y^2+z^2]^{3/2}},\\ \vec{B}(t,x,y,z) &= \vec{V} \times \vec{E}(t,x,y,z)/c, \end{align} \tag{3} \label{eq3}     $$ where $\gamma=(1-V^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$. It is now a nice exercise to verify explicitly that the electromagnetic field given in \eqref{eq3} together with \eqref{eq2} satisfies indeed Maxwell's equations \eqref{eq1}.

Comment: Thanks; sounds like all the answer is that as Coloumb's law field needs to update with the movement of the particle, the transition mixes old and new fields. All are radial, but not spherically symmetrical, providing a non-zero curl, yet no radiation? They come about in the ordinary course of the retarded update of the field per Coulomb's law...?

Comment: @Daniel Only accelerated charges radiate (with the characteristic $~1/r$ decrease of the field strength). In the present case of a motion with constant velocity, there is no radiation and the field falls off with $~1/r^2$. All this should be discussed in a good course on theoretical electrodynamics.

Comment: Thanks; (in my summary I was saying 'yet no radiation' to confirm the point.) May I bother you about a different thing - let's say a particle started to accelerate and emit radiation. And the radiation got absorbed in some material. What is the mechanism making the radiation field's magnitude smaller post absorption?